# How to configure a build mechanism that works with both IntelliJ and Team City

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, teamcity

So I don't have a code example for you here (as it really doesn't make sense) but I am trying to figure out how one would write or engineer a building and deployment mechanism such that it is understandable by both IntelliJ (for development purposes) and then Team City (for CI and deployment purposes).

I have experimented with the TeamCity Kotlin DSL - which is pretty powerful - but can't see a way of being able to define my builds just once. If I add something to an IntelliJ gradle file, I need to duplicate these library dependencies on TeamCity and vice versa.

Am I missing something obvious ?!

Comment: not clear why do you need to duplicate library dependencies. if you put dependency into `gradle.build` then on teamcity you have to run gradle build step...

Comment: Gradle pretty much works for all platforms. What have you tried?

Comment: The issue is when you start expanding the DSL to do some clever stuff on teamcity - hence the reason to use the DSL in the first place. I am thinking that in order to keep the two in sync, then the majority of the task/ dependency creation should be done in gradle